# Del Inspiron laptop no longer able to detect SSD

Tags: ssd, bios, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop was working fine when it suddenly broke down. When it boots, it shows the error message: "No hard drive detected, please try to resolve the issue by reseating the drive."

When I went into BIOS, the hard drive was not listed there either. My hard drive is a COSAIR SSD; SATA mode is set to AHCI correctly.

I thought my hard drive died; so I went to buy a brand new one. But after installing the new one, I still got the same error message.

At this time, I think the motherboard has faulted. What is my option now? Is it possible to repair the motherboard, or is it better to just replace it? Is it even worth replacing it?

Comment: It sounds like the motherboard is indeed bad.   Unless the laptop is under warranty its unlikely you will be able to replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the fact that the SSD does not have the same height as the regular HDD, if you plug it in without the plastic lid it should detect it, there are a few adapters available online or you can try to tweak it to plug in correctly with the lid attached. You can also try to guide the HD as you insert it into the bay so that it lines up with the SATA plugs, you will know it worked if it requires a little extra pull to get it in, when it goes in effortlessly then it probably didn't hook up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not convinced that motherboard would suddenly die and think SSD does not exist. On the other hand, it is a common symptom for SSD that went bad to disappear from BIOS.

When you put in the new drive, does it also not showing up in BIOS?

Dell Inspiron 1545 does not come with SSD. Do you still have the HDD that comes with it? I would first inspect the SATA connector on the laptop carefully to make sure there is no foreign objects and insert the HDD.

Last resort, laptops can usually be boot up via USB. So you have an option of repurposing the laptop w/ Linux on USB. It is possible to boot Windows but it is a lot harder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I put in the new drive, it doesn't show up in BIOS either. I no longer have the original HDD come with the laptop; I can try to find one and give it a try. Running Windows on USB is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

Last ditch efforts, disconnect power cord, remove battery, hold power button down for 30 seconds, reconnect power cord, see it it detects the drive now. If no joy do the same thing but also remove the cmos battery for 15 minutes, reinsert cmos battery and connect power cord and immediately go into the bios and set the date and time, then load default settings, save changes to bios and power down, restart and see if the drive is detected in the bios. Cmos battery access may require dis-assembly of the laptop

[Your Dell Servcie manual](http://Last%20ditch%20efforts,%20disconnect%20power%20cord,%20remove%20battery,%20hold%20power%20button%20down%20for%2030%20seconds,%20reconnect%20power%20cord,%20see%20it%20it%20detects%20the%20drive%20now.%20If%20no%20joy%20do%20the%20same%20thing%20but%20also%20remove%20the%20cmos%20battery%20for%2015%20minutes,%20reinsert%20cmos%20battery%20and%20connect%20power%20cord%20and%20immediately%20go%20into%20the%20bios%20and%20set%20the%20date%20and%20time,%20then%20load%20default%20settings,%20save%20changes%20to%20bios%20and%20power%20down,%20restart%20and%20see%20if%20the%20drive%20is%20detected%20in%20the%20bios.%20Cmos%20battery%20access%20may%20require%20dis-assembly%20of%20the%20laptop)